# Create mock and stub method that returns self mock

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking, phpunit, codeception

I have a class as follows:

```
class Foo extends BaseObject {

    public static function grab() {
        // do some DB search and return an instance of self
        // with the data in the object
        return new Foo($id);
    }

    public function insert() {
        // insert the data in the database for this object
        return false;
    }

    public function delete() {
        // delete the data from the database for this object
        return false;
    }

}
```

How can I mock this object, while still retain the ability to assert that invocations to `insert` and `delete` are behaving as expected?

What I've done is this: `use AspectMock\Test;`

```
    $mock = Test::double('Foo', [
        'grab' => Stub::make('Foo'),
        'insert' => true,
        'delete' => true,
    ]);

    // ... later in the test ...

    self::assertSame($foo->insert(), true);

    $mock->verifyInvoked('insert', 1);
```

This bypasses the mock for the `insert` and `update` methods, and returns `false` instead of the expected `true`. It also doesn't count the invocations as expected.

So how can I get the mock to return itself?

(Please forgive any confusion between `mock` and `stub` that I may have made)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [Phake](https://phake.readthedocs.io/) to mock static method, [as described here in the doc](https://phake.readthedocs.io/en/2.1/mocking-statics.html), as example:

```
public function testInsert()
{
    /** @var \App\Foo $classUnderTest */
    $classUnderTest = $this->getMockBuilder(Foo::class)
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->onlyMethods(['insert'])
        ->getMock();

    $classUnderTest->expects($this->once())
        ->method('insert')
        ->willReturn(true);

    /** @var \App\Foo $fooGrab */
    $fooGrab = \Phake::mock(Foo::class);
    \Phake::whenStatic($fooGrab)
        ->grab()
        ->thenReturn($classUnderTest);

    $mock = $fooGrab::grab();

    $this->assertTrue($mock->insert());
}
```

Comment: I was hoping to be able to do this without importing another whole package just to get this one test to pass.

Comment: @Benjam I understand but PHPUnit does not support static mock and seems Codeception also. Which testing framework you're actually in that project?

Comment: AspectMock is also available as part of that package. We are using Codeception, which uses PHPUnit as it's base.